# Need help displaying buttons dynamically from array data and displaying different text on each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to display four buttons, which is the amount of rows in my test database. I successfully grabbed the data from the database, parsed the JSON and stored it into 3 arrays, idStore, firstStore, and lastStore. Lets say we have in idStore [1,2,3,4] firstName [f1, f2, f3, f4] and lastName [l1,l2,l3,l4]. I want to display four buttons like this:

1 f1 l1

2 f2 l2

3 f3 l3

4 f4 l4

Right now, I found another answer on here that helped me get the amount of buttons on the page dynamically equal to idStore.length (so it creates four buttons on index.html). The problem is I don't know how to change the button text using angular. I tried getting the text to be displayed using $scope.names, but it is just a blank button with a comma in the middle. I want the button text to be my data right as they are created. I know my information is fine, because onButtonClicked successfully displays the data for the specified index in the console log.

displaydata.js

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl' , function($scope){
        $scope.number = idStore.length;
        $scope.getArray = function(num){
            var array = [];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < num;i++){
                array[i] = i +1;
            }
            return array;
        }
        $scope.names = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < idStore.length; i++)
            {
                [{first:firstStore[i], last:lastStore[i]}]
            }
        }

        $scope.getButtonClicked = function(buttonNumber){
            console.log(idStore[buttonNumber] + " " + firstStore[buttonNumber] + " " + lastStore[buttonNumber]);
        }
});
```

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="myController">

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button ng-repeat="n in getArray(number)" id="button-{{$index}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked($index)" >{{names.first}},{{names.last}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say, this is an odd way to go about things. Why not have a single array of objects returned from your JSON with an id, firstName, and lastName properties? Anyway, there's some issues with the way you've done this. You've defined `names` as a function, but then you are trying to use it as an object with properties. Also, it's not clear where `idStore` is from in your controller since I don't see it declared or injected anywhere. However you say that part is working so I think you can simplify things by changing your HTML markup for your button to this:

```
<button ng-repeat="id in idStore" id="button-{{$index}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked($index)">
    {{firstStore[$index]}}, {{lastStore[$index]}}
</button>
```

You can get rid of everything in your controller except the `getButtonClicked` function.

Comment: This worked, thank you. And yes you're right, I could just use the single array approach. I am quite new to using JSON, pulling from databases, angular, etc so I have been trying to teach myself over this past week.

Answer (score 0):

Create JSON array object instead of individual arrays.

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl' , function($scope){
        $scope.idflStore = [{'id': 1, 'first': 'f1', 'last': 'l1'},{'id': 2, 'first': 'f2', 'last': 'l2'},{'id': 3, 'first': 'f3', 'last': 'l3'},{'id': 4, 'first': 'f4', 'last': 'l4'}];

        $scope.getButtonClicked = function(buttonNumber){
            console.log(idStore[buttonNumber] + " " + firstStore[buttonNumber] + " " + lastStore[buttonNumber]);
        }
});
```

HTML file

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="displaydata.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<div>
    <div >
        <button ng-repeat="name in idflStore" id="button-{{$index}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked($index)" >
            {{name.id}},{{name.first}},{{name.last}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```